# Magento 2 pass data from template phtml to js file

Tags: magento2, javascript, ajax, requirejs, parameter

I want to call an ajax function on a button click. All other things are working fine. But I can't read the parameter which is passed to the js.  How can I do it? Here is my code.

Phtml file

```
    <div>
    <div id="successmsg" class="success message" style="display:none">Success</div>

    <input type="text" id="name" class="name" maxlength="8" placeholder="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('ENTER NAME')) ?>">
    <input type="button" value="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('CHECK')) ?>" id="check-button">
</div>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
   "#check-button": { 
       "Company_Module/js/check": {"ajaxurl":"<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getCheckUrl())?>"} 
   } 
} 
</script>
```

JS File

```
require([
    "jquery",
    'mage/template',
    "mage/mage"
], function ($, mageTemplate, alert){

    $('#check-button').click(function(){  
        jQuery("#successmsg").css('display','none');      
        $.ajax({
           url: config.ajaxurl,
           type: 'POST',
           dataType: 'json',
           data: {name: $('#name').val()},
           complete: function(response) {   
              if (response.responseJSON.success) {
                 jQuery("#successmsg").attr('style','display: block');                 
           },

        });            
    });
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your Js module should return function, to obtain configuration from .phtml; And also register your requireJs module by using *define([], function(){})*;

So should be like:

```
define([
    "jquery",
    'mage/template',
    "mage/mage"
], function ($, mageTemplate, alert){
    return function(config) {
        $('#check-button').click(function(){
            jQuery("#successmsg").css('display','none');
            $.ajax({
               url: config.ajaxurl,
               type: 'POST',
               dataType: 'json',
               data: {name: $('#name').val()},
               complete: function(response) {
                  if (response.responseJSON.success) {
                      jQuery("#successmsg").attr('style', 'display: block');
                  }
               }
            });
        });
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data from phtml template file to your custom Javascript module using either data-mage-init or x-magento-init, the only rule is that your JS module has to return a function, in order to have access to the *config* object:

Using data-mage-init :

```
<div id="unique" data-mage-init='{
        "Vendor_Module/js/model/fact-check": {
            "factProducts": <?= /* @noEscape */ $viewModel->getFactList() ?>,
            "currentFact": "<?= /* @noEscape */ $currentFact ?>"
        }}'> </div>
```

Using x-magento-init :

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                "components": {
                    "fact-checker": {
                        "component": "Vendor_Module/js/model/fact-check",
                        "factProducts": <?= /* @noEscape */ $viewModel->getFactList() ?>,
                        "currentFact": "<?= /* @noEscape */ $currentFact ?>"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

In your custom JS module :

```
define([
  'jquery'
], function($) {
  return function(config, element) {
    'use strict';

    const factProducts = config.factProducts;
    const currentFact = config.currentFact;

    // Your custom logic here

  }
});
```

Keep in mind that if you use a ui component with the **data-bind="scope: 'fact-checker'"**  binding, the JS errors will be silent and not show up in console.